# Changing Mavlink Message Rate ArduPilotMega

Tags: c++, robotics, dronekit, mavlink

I am working on a project that uses Mavlink protocol (in c++) to communicate with the ArduPilotMega (2.6).
I am able to read messages such as [ATTITUDE](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/#ATTITUDE) for example. The current message rate (for all messages) is 2Hz and I would like to increase this rate.
I found out that I should probably set [MESSAGE_INTERVAL](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/#MESSAGE_INTERVAL) using `MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL` in order to change it.

So my question is:
How do I send this command message using mavlink in c++?

I tried doing it using the code below but it did not work. I guess I have to use the command I mentioned above, but I don't know how.

```
mavlink_message_t command;
mavlink_message_interval_t interval;

interval.interval_us = 100000;
interval.message_id = 30;

mavlink_msg_message_interval_encode(255, 200, &command, &interval);
p_sensorsPort->write_message(command);
```

**Update:** I also tried this code below, maybe I am not giving it the right system id or component id.

```
mavlink_message_t command;
mavlink_command_long_t interval;

interval.param1 = MAVLINK_MSG_ID_ATTITUDE;
interval.param2 = 100000;
interval.command = MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL;
interval.target_system = 0;
interval.target_component = 0;

mavlink_msg_command_long_encode(255, 0, &command, &interval);
p_sensorsPort->write_message(command);
```

Maybe I am missing something about the difference between `target_system`, `target_component` and `sysid`, `compid`. I tried few values for each but nothing worked.
Is there any ACK that will be able to tell me if it even got the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Robotis Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/9923/change-message-interval-ardupilot) answer,

In order to change the message rate, the simplest way is to change the **SR_*** parameters value using [Mission Planner](http://ardupilot.org/planner/docs/common-install-mission-planner.html). The maximum rate is 10Hz.
For example, in order to change the [ATTITUDE](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/#ATTITUDE) message rate to be 10Hz I just had to change the **SR_EXTRA1** parameter to be 10.

For more information about which parameter changes each message see [GCS_Mavlink.cpp](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/master/ArduCopter/GCS_Mavlink.cpp#L821) file in ArduCopter firmware.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed start_stop field. the below sample is working.

```
        final msg_request_data_stream msg = new msg_request_data_stream ();
        msg.req_message_rate = rate;
        msg.req_stream_id = (short) streamId;
        msg.target_component = (short)compID;
        msg.target_system = (short)sysID;

        /*
                            GCS_COMMON.cpp contains code that sends when value =1
                            and stop when value = 0
                             that is  it.
        */

        if (rate > 0) {
            msg.start_stop = 1;
        } else {
            msg.start_stop = 0;
        }
```